# An Authentication object was not found in the SecurityContext (Spring 2.5.2)

Tags: spring, authentication, spring-security

I'm using Spring 2.5.2 and same version of spring security.
Issue is, I login through the application and clears my browser cookies and refreshes the page application is redirected to the login page but at the back it throws following exception

> DEBUG ExceptionTranslationFilter      - Authentication exception occurred; redirecting to authentication entry point
>   org.springframework.security.AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException: An Authentication object was not found in the SecurityContext
>       at org.springframework.security.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.credentialsNotFound(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:342)
>       at org.springframework.security.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.beforeInvocation(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:254)
>       at org.springframework.security.intercept.web.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:106)
>       at org.springframework.security.intercept.web.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
>       at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
>       at org.springframework.security.ui.SessionFixationProtectionFilter.doFilterHttp(SessionFixationProtectionFilter.java:52)
>       at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
>       at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)

Continue till `at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)`

After this exception application is redirected to the login page & after entering the login credentials 
I have to click my login button twice to enter into the application.
After the first click console shows

> DEBUG CptLogger                       - com.capgent.cpt.server.services.auth.LoginAuthenticationProvider Method invoked : additionalAuthenticationChecks isAuthenticated ? :false
>   DEBUG XmlWebApplicationContext        - Publishing event in context [org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext@1d0d124]: org.springframework.security.event.authentication.AuthenticationSuccessEvent[source=org.springframework.security.providers.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@862413dc: Principal: com.capgent.cpt.server.services.auth.UserDetailsContainer@bc1ebd; Password: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.ui.WebAuthenticationDetails@0: RemoteIpAddress: 127.0.0.1; SessionId: 6693D3BCE880D6339D9D149F44637952; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ADMIN]
>   DEBUG AuthenticationProcessingFilter  - Authentication success: org.springframework.security.providers.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@862413dc: Principal: com.capgent.cpt.server.services.auth.UserDetailsContainer@bc1ebd; Password: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.ui.WebAuthenticationDetails@0: RemoteIpAddress: 127.0.0.1; SessionId: 6693D3BCE880D6339D9D149F44637952; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ADMIN
>   DEBUG AuthenticationProcessingFilter  - Updated SecurityContextHolder to contain the following Authentication: 'org.springframework.security.providers.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@862413dc: Principal: com.capgent.cpt.server.services.auth.UserDetailsContainer@bc1ebd; Password: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.ui.WebAuthenticationDetails@0: RemoteIpAddress: 127.0.0.1; SessionId: 6693D3BCE880D6339D9D149F44637952; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ADMIN'
>   DEBUG SessionUtils                    - Invalidating session with Id '6693D3BCE880D6339D9D149F44637952' and migrating attributes.
>   DEBUG SessionUtils                    - Started new session: E772A0D1441C079B2ACD3698F68AF63C
>   DEBUG AuthenticationProcessingFilter  - Redirecting to target URL from HTTP Session (or default): `http://localhost:8090/resources/com.capgent.cpt.Main/Main.jsp`
>   DEBUG omTokenBasedRemembermeServices  - Did not send remember-me cookie (principal did not set parameter '_spring_security_remember_me')
>   DEBUG omTokenBasedRemembermeServices  - Remember-me login not requested.
>   DEBUG XmlWebApplicationContext        - Publishing event in context [org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext@1d0d124]: org.springframework.security.event.authentication.InteractiveAuthenticationSuccessEvent[source=org.springframework.security.providers.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@862413dc: Principal: com.capgent.cpt.server.services.auth.UserDetailsContainer@bc1ebd; Password: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.ui.WebAuthenticationDetails@0: RemoteIpAddress: 127.0.0.1; SessionId: 6693D3BCE880D6339D9D149F44637952; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ADMIN]
>   DEBUG essionContextIntegrationFilter  - SecurityContext stored to HttpSession: 'org.springframework.security.context.SecurityContextImpl@862413dc: Authentication: org.springframework.security.providers.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@862413dc: Principal: com.capgent.cpt.server.services.auth.UserDetailsContainer@bc1ebd; Password: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.ui.WebAuthenticationDetails@0: RemoteIpAddress: 127.0.0.1; SessionId: 6693D3BCE880D6339D9D149F44637952; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ADMIN'
>   DEBUG essionContextIntegrationFilter  - SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
>   DEBUG RequestContextFilter            - Cleared thread-bound request context: org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@1d03700
>   DEBUG nsactionSynchronizationManager  - Removed value [org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SessionHolder@1c9dea3] for key [org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl@42c282] from thread [http-8090-Processor25]
>   DEBUG OpenSessionInViewFilter         - Closing single Hibernate Session in OpenSessionInViewFilter
>   DEBUG SessionFactoryUtils             - Closing Hibernate Session
>   DEBUG ConnectionManager               - releasing JDBC connection [ (open PreparedStatements: 0, globally: 0) (open ResultSets: 0, globally: 0)]
>   DEBUG ConnectionManager               - transaction completed on session with on_close connection release mode; be sure to close the session to release JDBC resources!
>   DEBUG OpenSessionInViewFilter         - Using SessionFactory 'cptSessionFactory' for OpenSessionInViewFilter
>   DEBUG DefaultListableBeanFactory      - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'cptSessionFactory'
>   DEBUG OpenSessionInViewFilter         - Opening single Hibernate Session in OpenSessionInViewFilter
>   DEBUG SessionFactoryUtils             - Opening Hibernate Session
>   DEBUG SessionImpl                     - opened session at timestamp: 13938439638
>   DEBUG nsactionSynchronizationManager  - Bound value [org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SessionHolder@862557] for key [org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl@42c282] to thread [http-8090-Processor25]
>   DEBUG RequestContextFilter            - Bound request context to thread: org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@1d03700
>   DEBUG FilterChainProxy                - Converted URL to lowercase, from: '/com.capgent.cpt.main/main.jsp'; to: '/com.capgent.cpt.main/main.jsp'
>   DEBUG FilterChainProxy                - Candidate is: '/com.capgent.cpt.main/main.jsp'; pattern is /ssoerror.html*; matched=false
>   DEBUG FilterChainProxy                - Converted URL to lowercase, from: '/com.capgent.cpt.main/main.jsp'; to: '/com.capgent.cpt.main/main.jsp'
>   DEBUG FilterChainProxy                - Candidate is: '/com.capgent.cpt.main/main.jsp'; pattern is /**; matched=true
>   DEBUG FilterChainProxy                - /com.capgent.cpt.Main/Main.jsp at position 1 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'org.springframework.security.context.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter[ order=200; ]'
>   DEBUG essionContextIntegrationFilter  - Obtained a valid SecurityContext from SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT to associate with SecurityContextHolder: 'org.springframework.security.context.SecurityContextImpl@862413dc: Authentication: org.springframework.security.providers.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@862413dc: Principal: com.capgent.cpt.server.services.auth.UserDetailsContainer@bc1ebd; Password: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.ui.WebAuthenticationDetails@0: RemoteIpAddress: 127.0.0.1; SessionId: 6693D3BCE880D6339D9D149F44637952; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ADMIN'
>   DEBUG FilterChainProxy                - /com.capgent.cpt.Main/Main.jsp at position 2 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'com.capgent.cpt.server.services.auth.CantrexSsoProcessingFilter[ order=600; ]'
>   DEBUG FilterChainProxy                - /com.capgent.cpt.Main/Main.jsp at position 3 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'com.capgent.cpt.server.services.auth.DnbiSsoProcessingFilter[ order=600; ]'
>   DEBUG FilterChainProxy                - /com.capgent.cpt.Main/Main.jsp at position 4 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'com.capgent.cpt.server.services.auth.OpenIdAuthenticationProcessingFilter[ order=800; ]'
>   DEBUG FilterChainProxy                - /com.capgent.cpt.Main/Main.jsp at position 5 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'org.springframework.security.ui.webapp.AuthenticationProcessingFilter[ order=700; ]'
>   DEBUG FilterChainProxy                - /com.capgent.cpt.Main/Main.jsp at position 6 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'org.springframework.security.wrapper.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter[ order=1100; ]'
>   DEBUG SavedRequest                    - pathInfo: both null (property equals)
>   DEBUG SavedRequest                    - queryString: both null (property equals)
>   DEBUG SavedRequest                    - requestURI: arg1=/resources/com.capgent.cpt.Main/Main.jsp; arg2=/resources/com.capgent.cpt.Main/Main.jsp (property equals)
>   DEBUG SavedRequest                    - serverPort: arg1=8090; arg2=8090 (property equals)
>   DEBUG SavedRequest                    - requestURL: arg1=`http://localhost:8090/resources/com.capgent.cpt.Main/Main.jsp`; arg2=`http://localhost:8090/resources/com.capgent.cpt.Main/Main.jsp` (property equals)
>   DEBUG SavedRequest                    - scheme: arg1=http; arg2=http (property equals)
>   DEBUG SavedRequest                    - serverName: arg1=localhost; arg2=localhost (property equals)
>   DEBUG SavedRequest                    - contextPath: arg1=/resources; arg2=/resources (property equals)
>   DEBUG SavedRequest                    - servletPath: arg1=/com.capgent.cpt.Main/Main.jsp; arg2=/com.capgent.cpt.Main/Main.jsp (property equals)
>   DEBUG SavedRequestAwareWrapper        - Wrapper replaced; SavedRequest was: SavedRequest[http://localhost:8090/resources/com.capgent.cpt.Main/Main.jsp]
>   DEBUG FilterChainProxy                - /com.capgent.cpt.Main/Main.jsp at position 7 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'org.springframework.security.ui.rememberme.RememberMeProcessingFilter[ order=1200; ]'
>   DEBUG RememberMeProcessingFilter      - SecurityContextHolder not populated with remember-me token, as it already contained: 'org.springframework.security.providers.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@862413dc: Principal: com.capgent.cpt.server.services.auth.UserDetailsContainer@bc1ebd; Password: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.ui.WebAuthenticationDetails@0: RemoteIpAddress: 127.0.0.1; SessionId: 6693D3BCE880D6339D9D149F44637952; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ADMIN'
>   DEBUG FilterChainProxy                - /com.capgent.cpt.Main/Main.jsp at position 8 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'org.springframework.security.ui.ExceptionTranslationFilter[ order=1400; ]'
>   DEBUG FilterChainProxy                - /com.capgent.cpt.Main/Main.jsp at position 9 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'org.springframework.security.ui.SessionFixationProtectionFilter[ order=1600; ]'
>   DEBUG FilterChainProxy                - /com.capgent.cpt.Main/Main.jsp at position 10 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'org.springframework.security.intercept.web.FilterSecurityInterceptor@11ca33b'
>   DEBUG lterInvocationDefinitionSource  - Converted URL to lowercase, from: '/com.capgent.cpt.main/main.jsp'; to: '/com.capgent.cpt.main/main.jsp'
>   DEBUG lterInvocationDefinitionSource  - Candidate is: '/com.capgent.cpt.main/main.jsp'; pattern is /**/*main.jsp; matched=true
>   DEBUG AbstractSecurityInterceptor     - Secure object: FilterInvocation: URL: /com.capgent.cpt.Main/Main.jsp; ConfigAttributes: [ROLE_ADMIN]
>   DEBUG AbstractSecurityInterceptor     - Previously Authenticated: org.springframework.security.providers.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@862413dc: Principal: com.capgent.cpt.server.services.auth.UserDetailsContainer@bc1ebd; Password: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.ui.WebAuthenticationDetails@0: RemoteIpAddress: 127.0.0.1; SessionId: 6693D3BCE880D6339D9D149F44637952; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ADMIN
>   DEBUG AbstractSecurityInterceptor     - Authorization successful
>   DEBUG XmlWebApplicationContext        - Publishing event in context [org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext@1d0d124]: org.springframework.security.event.authorization.AuthorizedEvent[source=FilterInvocation: URL: /com.capgent.cpt.Main/Main.jsp]
>   DEBUG AbstractSecurityInterceptor     - RunAsManager did not change Authentication object
>   DEBUG FilterChainProxy                - /com.capgent.cpt.Main/Main.jsp reached end of additional filter chain; proceeding with original chain
>   DEBUG JspServlet                      - JspEngine --> /com.capgent.cpt.Main/Main.jsp
>   DEBUG JspServlet                      -          ServletPath: /com.capgent.cpt.Main/Main.jsp
>   DEBUG JspServlet                      -             PathInfo: null
>   DEBUG JspServlet                      -             RealPath: D:\springworkspace.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp3\wtpwebapps\capgentspring\com.capgent.cpt.Main\Main.jsp
>   DEBUG JspServlet                      -           RequestURI: /resources/com.capgent.cpt.Main/Main.jsp
>   DEBUG JspServlet                      -          QueryString: null

Comment: How does your 'spring security' configuration xml looks like ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the 
`<form-login login-page="/Login.jsp" authentication-failure-url="/LoginHandler.jsp" always-use-default-target="true" default-target-url="/LoginHandler.jsp"/>`

has solved my issue earlier the value was `alway-use-default-target="false"`

Answer (score 1):

**"Issue is, I login through the application and clears my browser cookies and refreshes the page application is redirected to the login page"**

Yes.It is the Normal behavior. Because a new session will be started from there since the old session was invalidated/closed.

**"but at the back it throws following exception"**

Yes.It will, because it tries to revalidate the user info/session when you refresh the page.Since you have already cleared the cookies, it will fail.